# $6$ persons enter the train during the journey with $6$ different tickets of the same class. How many different sets of ticket may they have had?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification

A train going from Cambridge to London stops at nine intermediate stations. $6$ persons enter the train during the journey with $6$ different tickets of the same class. How many different sets of ticket may they have had?

My attempt is as follows:-

**Attempt $1$:**

So as there are $10$ possible destinations (London + $9$ intermediate stations) , so there will be $10$ different tickets.

So as 6 people have 6 different tickets, so different sets of tickets which they can have will be $\displaystyle{10\choose 6}$. But actual answer is $\displaystyle {45\choose 6}$. So I tried some different approach.

**Attempt $2$**:

May be the uniqueness of the ticket is suppose to be determined by the source and destination.

There are $10$ sources and $10$ destinations, hence no of different tickets will be $\left(10+9+8\cdots\cdots+1\right)=55$.

So different sets of tickets which they can have will be $\displaystyle{55\choose 6}$, but not matching the actual answer $\displaystyle {45\choose 6}$

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Give $11$stops there are ${11 \choose 2}=55$ trips that one can take.  Then you choose six of the possible tickets in ${55 \choose 6}$ ways.  I agree with you.

Comment: Suppose cambridge is the source, so $1,2,3,4,5\cdots\cdots 9, \text{ London }$ are $10$ destinations for cambridge, so thats why $10+9+8+\cdots\cdots1$

Comment: and by the way there are total $11$ stations including Cambridge and London ,so shouldn't it be $\displaystyle{11\choose 2}$ type of tickets.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Fixed.

Comment: but generally uniqueness of the ticket is determined by the destination alone right? Here they are making us to define a ticket based on source and destination pairs.

Comment: No, I would say the ticket depends on both the source and destination.  A ticket from Cambridge to London probably costs more than a ticket from the next to last stop to London.

Comment: but if you are differentiating only on the basis of prices, can't it be that two pairs of stations have similar prices.

Comment: I was just using that as an example why tickets should differ depending on source as well as destination.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if the passengers enter the train 'during' the journey, Cambridge station is not a possible source.

Comment: yeah , I also thought so but then I thought I am over emphasizing the language, so not sure whether $\displaystyle{45\choose 6}$ is due to the phrase "during the journey" or it is because of something else.