# In how many ways can the tickets be purchased?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations, combinations

A train is running between Patna to Howrah. Seven
people enter the train somewhere between Patna and
Howrah. It is given that nine stops are there in between Patna and Howrah. In how many ways can
the tickets be purchased if no restriction is there
with respect to the number of tickets at any station?
2 people do not buy the same ticket.

**The answer is 45!/(7!*38!), the answer would br right considering it as a combination. Can anyone explain how it is a combination, can't it be permutation since all the persons are different? ( in that case the answer would be 45!/38!)***

Comment: Both answers are correct given their particular interpretation.  The $\frac{45!}{7!38!}$ works for saying a pattern is something like "one ticket from Asansol to Burdwan, one ticket from  Asansol to Howrah, ...".  The $\frac{45!}{38!}$ works for saying a pattern is something like "Mrs Banerjee buys a ticket from Asansol to Burdwan, Mr Dasgupta buys a ticket from  Asansol to Howrah, ..." with them swapping routes being a different pattern.

Comment: For related question with different ambiguities, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576461/trip-from-london-to-cambridge and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519278/6-persons-enter-the-train-during-the-journey-with-6-different-tickets-of-the